# in job MapReduce , which time I choose ?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

to study the Performance in hadoop I run SEVERAL test mapreduce

the objectif is to comparare between tests

but which time i choose (real or user or sys) ?

```
time hadoop jar class input output

real    2m48.886s
user    0m3.300s
sys 0m0.304s
```